# how to add label on flowLayoutPanel1 at first index0?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to add label on flowLayoutPanel1 at first index0?
i would like to put label control in first or secound index how?
that readonly?

```
Label lb = new Label();
lb.AutoSize = true;
lb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(187)))), ((int)(((byte)(206)))), ((int)(((byte)(241)))));
lb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(122, 3);
lb.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 3, 3, 0);
lb.Name = "label2";
lb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 13);
lb.TabIndex = 13;
lb.Text = "XXX";
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[0] = lb?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Controls.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add.aspx) to add the label to `flowLayoutPanel1`, and then use [`SetChildIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx) to set the index of the control to whatever you want:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lb);              // Adds lb to flowLayoutPanel1
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(lb, 0); // Sets index of lb to 0
```

Comment: Yep, that was my mistake. Fixed now.